# mongodb pull an array from several object in an array of one document

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

here is a document in mongo:

```
{ 
  _id: objectid,
  user: objectid,
  company: objectid,
  groups:[
    {items:['a','b']}, {items:['c','d']}
  ]
}
```

then, i got a array:

```
 ['a','c']
```

i want to pull this array from above document
and i want to operate above document , finally i want the above document be like this:

```
{ 
  _id: objectid,
  user: objectid,
  company: objectid,
  groups:[
    {items:['b']}, {items:['d']}
  ]
}
```

how to get this result in mongo

i'm desire helps

thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can make that kind of query natively in Mongo. Just pull your document, then filter `groups` according to your needs, and pass the altered document.

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry, i may not describe the question clear or you made me confused, i edited my question again ,  i want to use the array ['a','c'] to operate the above document , change the above document to become i wanted in one step , i beg your help and patience, thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, so you want to pull it, alter it and then re-save it? I didn't get that indeed. But it looks like your question is a duplicate, follow the link above, it'll help you.

Comment: @JeremyThille you got it and thank you, i will follow the link above